# Unable to prove the transitive relation for path connected sets

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

> Let (X,T) be a topological space and define a relation ~ on X by x~y provided that there is a pathwise connected subset A of X such that x,y $\in A$. Prove that ~ is an equivalence relation on X.

I tried by assuming f(0)=x and f(1)=y and f'(0)=y and f'(1)= z. But I need to find a function, f* such that f*(0)=x and f*(1)=y.

But unable to do so. Can you please help in constructiong such a funtion.

Comment: How about joining the two paths together? I.e., consider $$g(t)=\begin{cases}f(2t)&t<0.5\\f'(2t-1)&t\geq0.5\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f,f':[0,1] \to X$ are the equired paths define their composition

$$f \ast f'(t):=\begin{cases}
f(2t) & t \in [0,\frac12]\\
f'(2t-1) & t \in [\frac12,1]
\end{cases}$$

for $t \in [0,1]$. This is well-defined as $(f \ast f')(\frac12)$ is defined both as $f(1) = y$ and $f'(0)=y$. Both domain sets are closed, so by the [pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma) we have that this function is continuous whenever $f$ and $f'$ are. So it's a continuous path from $x$ to $z$ as required.

For symmetry we use $f'(t)= f(1-t)$ when $f$ is a path from $x$ to $y$ to make one from $y$ to $x$, and a constant map suffices to show reflexivity.